# Navigation app with custom GeoJSON data

Tags: android, navigation, mapbox, geojson

I am creating a navigation app in android studio using mapbox. I have created a GeoJSON file with custom data (walking paths with properties) using JOSM. I would like to know if there is a way to get navigation directions using this GeoJSON file and not from the mapbox driving routes?

Answer (score 0):

The Mapbox Navigation SDK is compatible with our [Map Matching API](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/navigation/overview/map-matching/), which may be helpful here.

If your GeoJSON file has a list of points (up to 100), you can give this to the API and it will return a "match" which you can then convert to a `DirectionsRoute` compatible with our SDK (see linked docs for full technical explanation).

To draw a GeoJSON data set on a `MapboxMap` check out [these docs](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/map-sdk/overview/runtime-styling/) and look for the `GeoJSON` title.

Unfortunately, if you're also looking for directions that the Navigation SDK can then parse / provide as directions, this won't be possible unless you assemble a custom `DirectionsRoute` yourself with your GeoJSON path data.

Comment: I have tried it but this matches the custom routes with the streets. I don't want that because inside my paths there are mountain paths that are not exist in the mapbox map. What i want to do ( i don't know if it can be done) is to display a map and, on the top of it, display a layer with my paths in which i want to navigate.

Comment: Updated my original comment ^